# I removed everything from ( /etc/hosts ) except for (127.0.0.1 localhost) and rebooted. but when i login it's still ( root@name )

Tags: linux

You know how when you login to the server
it shows something like..

root@something

well i removed everything from `/etc/hosts` file
except for localhost

```
 127.0.0.1       localhost
```

and then rebooted

well i still have the old servername next to root@
when i login.

what's going on ?

how am i suppose to test things if things are all random like this?

Comment: How's this related to any of those tags?

Comment: Or http://serverfault.com/?

Comment: Indeed rudeness going on there.....

Comment: You need to update your question. It's not clear why you change /etc/hosts and why you try to change the hostname of your computer. It seems those are your tries at fixing a problem which is not stated in the Question. Please edit it to include a problem related to application development or tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Redhat / CentOS / Fedora

```
vi /etc/sysconfig/network
```

Change the value of `HOSTNAME=` save it and close

If you are using Debian / Ubuntu

```
vi /etc/hostname
```

Change the value of `HOSTNAME=` save it and close

Answer (score 0):

/etc/hosts is where you map IP addresses to different hosts.
It does not contain the name of YOUR local server.

Depending on your Linux version, hostname is stored in one of the following:

```
/etc/sysconfig/network 

/etc/hostname
```

Comment: so do you know which one does?

Comment: Depends on your Linux version...

/etc/sysconfig/network
/etc/hostname

Those are the two that come to mind.

Comment: centos, ok looks like something is in /etc/hostname but it's not the same thing i have next to root@

Comment: how did this hostname get there exactly ? ( /etc/sysconfig/network ) i don't remember editing this file. did httpd.conf do this to this file ?

Comment: can the host name be deleted ?

Comment: Hostnames are created when you first installed Linux.

Comment: No, all computers require a valid hostname.